# Creating a shortcut icon on the Windows desktop

Tags: java, windows, desktop

How can I create a Windows shortcut alias for an existing exe file **from within a Java application**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows shortcuts are hoary beasts.  You could use JShortcut http://alumnus.caltech.edu/~jimmc/jshortcut/, which used JNI (Java Native Interface) to create the shortcut.  If you are just doing a quick utility you can also just use Runtime.exec() to call a VB script.

Comment: Just out of curiosity are there other libraries for other systems with similar functionality? Just in case if one every needs to create a multi platform installer.

Comment: I'm not aware of any others, and a quick google search didn't come up with anything, but I wouldn't say there aren't others out there.

Comment: cool anyway nice link and answer. I gave it +1 already. Thanks.

Comment: Check out the netbeans installer. It also uses a bunch of native libraries. I pulled out the relevant code and put it in s a simple jar file(still working on it) https://github.com/spyhunter99/shortcuthelper